# Disable notification when launching background service in python-for-android

Tags: android, python

I am following the instructions in:

http://kivy.org/planet/2014/01/building-a-background-application-on-android-with-kivy/

to run background service in python-for-android, but when I start a service, a notification shows up, and would not go away.

Is there a way to start a background service without this notification?

If not, is there a way to hide/change the notification content from the background service?